# How do I add a genereted resx file to my cproj programaticly

Tags: c#, resx

I am trying to add my code genereted resx file into my project.

I'm currently making a translation tool for my company. This tool gathers all items that need to be translated and makes a translation file. Then when translated it reads the new file and creates the nessesary resx files for every module. However I am unable to correctly add the resx files to the project.

I am using the ResXResourceWriter to generate the file and add all nessesary resource items. Then I try to ad it to the project with 'Microsoft.Build.Evaluasion.Project.AddItem' But for some reason the file isn't added correctly.

Some sample code for adding the file to the project

```
  var p = OpenProject(project.FullName);
  p.AddItem("Resources", newFileLocation);
  p.Save();
```

Sample code of creating the resx file

```
using (var newFile = new ResXResourceWriter(newFileLocation))
{
   for (var i = 0; i < baseResxFileXmlNodes.Count; i++)
   {
      var nodeName = baseResxFileXmlNodes[i].Attributes["name"].Value;
      var resxDataNode = new ResXDataNode(nodeName, translationDictionary[nodeName]);
      newFile.AddResource(resxDataNode);
   }
}
UpdateProject(fileInfo, newFileLocation);
```

Comment: When you say "it isn't added correctly" what do you mean? Does it show up in the project tree? Is it that the right designer isn't loaded when you click on it?